# How can I add existing files in mvc project?

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a controller, model, and view pages.
I want to add those file in a mvc razor .net project.
After I add and debug than it say "The resource cannot be found".

What is process of add those file in project?

Answer (score 0):

Do you included those files in project?

Another way is that you add controllers manuelly, with the same names, and then copy-paste the rest of it.